# strange behaviour of MVC RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirecttoaction

I have the following UserController methods:

```
public ActionResult DeleteThread(int RootMessageID)
{
    _repository.DeleteMessageThread(RootMessageID);
    return RedirectToAction("ActionMessageSuccess", new { txt = "Message was sent successfully" });
}
    public ActionResult ActionMessageSuccess(string txt)
    {
        return View(txt);
    }
```

have cshtml page (in Views\User):

```
@model System.String
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SendMessageSuccess";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutUser.cshtml";
}

<h2>@Model</h2>
```

but I got:

```
The view 'Message was sent successfully' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/User/Message was sent successfully.aspx
~/Views/User/Message was sent successfully.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Message was sent successfully.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Message was sent successfully.ascx
~/Views/User/Message was sent successfully.cshtml
~/Views/User/Message was sent successfully.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Message was sent successfully.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Message was sent successfully.vbhtml
```

after call DeleteThread. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with redirectToAction.

You are calling `RedirectToAction("ActionMessageSuccess", new { txt = "Message was sent successfully" });`

So it redirected to action ActionMessageSuccess with **txt** value.

With in ActionMessageSuccess you are returning a view with name txt i.e. "**Message was sent successfully**", but system unable to file a view with name "Message was sent successfully".

Comment: nothing understand. I see, that I pass actionName="ActionMessageSuccess" and routeValues = "new { txt = "Message was sent successfully" }". So, Method ActionMessageSuccess should be called with parameter txt = "Message was sent successfully". Where am I wrong?

Comment: oh, I found problem. Thank you!